# How to create singleton classes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, singleton

I am working on a large project where I have multiple managers to handle different tasks, I need an only a single object of these managers to be created when I start the app,

I came across this method of Singleton creation

```
class QuestionnaireManager {

  constructor() {
    if (this.instance) {
      return;
    }
    this.instance = this;
  }
}
```

Is this an acceptable way, is there any downside, I am coming from `JAVA` `Kotlin` background and this seems to simple to be true where we have so much to deal in case of singletons in other languages. (Most of those cases have to deal with multi-threading but as JS is single-threaded so I think this would be sufficient way)

Still need opinion on best practices, or any other Dependency Injection methods where we don't even rely on Singleton but create the object once and reuse all over the project with dependency injections.

I would like to know the opinion of sensie in JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Singleton.js

class Singleton {
    constructor(){
        if(Singleton._instance){
            console.warn("already created!");
            return Singleton._instance;
        }

        Singleton._instance = this;

        console.log("singleton created");

        this._createdTime = new Date();
    }

    static instance() {
        if(!Singleton._instance){
            return new Singleton();
        }

        return Singleton._instance;
    }

    createdTime() {
        return this._createdTime.toISOString();
    }
}

Singleton._instance = null;

export default Singleton;

// main.js

import Singleton from "./Singleton"

const a = new Singleton();
const b = new Singleton();
const c = Singleton.instance();

console.log(a.createdTime());
console.log(b.createdTime());
console.log(c.createdTime());
```

Output would be
[image]

Answer (score 18):

That ain't the right way to implement Singleton in ES6. The correct way:

```js
class QuestionnaireManager {
  constructor() {
    if (QuestionnaireManager._instance) {
      throw new Error("Singleton classes can't be instantiated more than once.")
    }
    QuestionnaireManager._instance = this;

    // ... your rest of the constructor code goes after this
  }
}

var managerOne = new QuestionnaireManager()
var managerTwo = new QuestionnaireManager() // Throws error
```

Or, if you don't want an error to be thrown on second instance creation you can just return the last instance, like so:

```js
class QuestionnaireManager {
  constructor() {
    if (QuestionnaireManager._instance) {
      return QuestionnaireManager._instance
    }
    QuestionnaireManager._instance = this;

    // ... your rest of the constructor code goes after this
  }
}

var managerOne = new QuestionnaireManager()
var managerTwo = new QuestionnaireManager()

console.log(managerOne === managerTwo) // logs "true"
```

Comment: How is this way technically different from what I was doing ? can you please elaborate, also I usually put `export new QuestionnaireManager()` at the bottom, so it is easy to just use functions inside QuestionnaireManager() without creating a specific object, is it also a right approach?

Comment: for example: QuestionnaireManager.doSomething(), as while exporting only we have created the object, which is a singleton so no need to create a new object

Comment: Well, that's okay to export the instance if it serves your purpose but if you see the OOP way it is inhibiting the features of *inheritance*. Let's say you want to extend this `QuestionnaireManager` class in the future to some `AdvancedQuestionnaireManager` class, you won't really be able to do that as it's the class only that can be extended and not the instance itself that you have exported.

Answer (score 3):

In javascript you can export an instance of a class to make a singleton

```js
// questionnaire-manager.js
class QuestionnaireManager {

  constructor() {
  }
}

module.exports = new QuestionnaireManager()
```

Then when you call `require('questionnaire-manager')` you'll always get the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

**Like Mikel B.'s answer only in a shorter syntax**

```
module.exports = new class foo {..}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30304597)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Singleton {
  constructor() {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      // Create a new instance of the class
      this.data = [];
      Singleton.instance = this;
    }

    return Singleton.instance;
  }

  // Add a method to the class
  addData(data) {
    this.data.push(data);
  }
}

// Create a new instance of the class
const instance1 = new Singleton();
instance1.addData('Hello');

// Try to create a second instance of the class
const instance2 = new Singleton();

console.log(instance1 === instance2); // true
console.log(instance1.data); // ['Hello']
console.log(instance2.data); // ['Hello']
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76094086/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need a static property, not instance property `this.instance`. It will be accessable by `QuestionnaireManager.instance` reference. But... it is sooo rare case to implement classical GOF singleton in Javascript... kind of enforcing yourself to develop UI in vim and feel yoursefl as "true develper" :)